# Sub menu not staying when hover on <a> tag

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to let my sub menu slide down and let it stay open. I know I can do it to set the hover on the `<li>` tag, but then when I hover on my ::after elements, it also opens, wich I do not want.

Anybody an idea how to let the sub menu (and sub sub,...) stay.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v9rnx7fg/

Comment: Unrelated comment: ***what** happened to your css? It's all over the place?

Comment: I think you need like: http://jsfiddle.net/v9rnx7fg/1/

Comment: @jbutler483 accidently copied also normalized stylesheet

Comment: I don't think you really need all that tbh - most of it is just adding 'extra stuff' that most likely won't be used/needed in production.

Comment: @ketan if you do it like that and then hover over the '|' (and margin before and after) it also drop down, but I don't want that

Comment: @ketan: grandchildren don't work ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is to do with your nesting - your hover event is on the anchor element, when the mouse goes out of the anchor elements boundary the onmouseout event is triggered and your submenu closes.

You'll need to apply your hover to the submenus parent li - then when the sub menu slides down and you move the mouse over that, you'll still be hovering over the parent element.

Hope that makes some sense?

EDIT: I changed the JS to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".level2, .level3, .level4").css('display', 'none');
    $(".media, .groepen").hover(

    function () {
        $('.back2').stop(true, false).slideDown('medium');
        $(this).closest('li').find('ul.level2').stop(true, false).slideDown('medium');
    },

    function () {
        $('.back2').stop(true, false).slideUp('medium');
        $(this).closest('li').find('ul.level2').stop(true, false).slideUp('medium');
    });
    $(".mediaSub").hover(

    function () {
        $(this).closest('li').find('ul.level3').stop(true, false).slideDown('medium');
    },

    function () {
        $(this).closest('li').find('ul.level3').stop(true, false).slideUp('medium');
    });
    $(".2014, .2015").hover(

    function () {
        $(this).closest('li').find('ul.level4').stop(true, false).slideDown('medium');
    },

    function () {
        $(this).closest('li').find('ul.level4').stop(true, false).slideUp('medium');
    });
});
```

This seems to work in Chrome - what browser are you seeing the separators trigger the menu?

Comment: Yeah I know that, but that if I do that, the ::after elements I add also trigger the hover and I don't want that

Comment: What browser? I changed $(".media > a, .groepen > a").hover( to $(".media, .groepen").hover( and it seems to work at the top level without the separators triggering the menu. I'm using Chrome...

Comment: Also chrome, but apperently I've used the ::before, not the ::after, so if you hover over the seperators before "Media" it triggers the hover.